# 19.5V to 15V - what's the best way to lower the voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, lm317

The problem is: I've got a power supply capable of outputting 19.5V 4A. I need to lower the voltage to power up a laptop that requires 15V and 2A. Which way is the best to do it? Construct a voltage divider from some resistors? Use a LM317?(datasheet says it can output "in excess of 1.5A" - what does it mean? That it will tolerate 2A?)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it might help you with some background knowledge about power supplies: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings
And this one on the idea of using a voltage divider:
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/111647/6334

Answer (score 1):

Use a buck regulator is realistically the sane choice. Maybe one of these: -

[image]

They appear to cost about £7 from ebay [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/170924663851?limghlpsr=true&hlpv=2&ops=true&viphx=1&hlpht=true&lpid=108&chn=ps&device=c&rlsatarget=&adtype=pla&crdt=0&ff3=1&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff12=67&ff13=80&ff14=108).

But, as always read the small print and check out a few others. I just googled "15V 3A buck regulator" and this was the first hit and I think it may be a little underpowered so go for something a tad beefier.

Comment: One I looked at was sold as "12A"- it had a 12A fuse and a chip with 8A (datasheet) capability. <sigh>