# Voltage divider resistor power disipation

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider, esp8266, power-dissipation

I am trying to create a power supply circuit for the [ESP8266](https://nurdspace.nl/ESP8266#Power), using a voltage divider and a cellphone charger rated at 5V, 1A as power supply.

I have resistors connected like this:

[image]

The resistors are rated at 1 - 6 W.
Using an online calculator for power dissipation i get 900W per resistor for the ESP8266 max current of 300mA. I am using 3 10K resistors with two in series for the 20K part.

I guess this is the correct reasoning.

Could someone explain if I'm doing something wrong and if this will work?

Comment: Look at Peter Bennett's answer here : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111646/is-it-safe-to-use-a-voltage-divider-for-arduino-and-dc-motor-controller?rq=1

Comment: A resistor voltage divider is not suitable for use as a power supply. Never. Not ever.

Comment: Yes but I'm asking because i don't have a regulator with me. What will happen in this circuit? Will the resistors melt?

Comment: The output voltage of the divider will vary depending on the current drawn from the output.  Your ESP8266 will effectively be a variable resistor in parallel with the 20 K resistor.  I believe the ESP8266 can draw 250 mA or so when transmitting - that would theoreticaly produce 2500 volts across the 10K resistor!!

Comment: So will I go up in smoke or burn something? :)

Comment: Ask yourself how much current can you get from a 10k resistor connected to a +5V supply - forget about the 20k resistor for now and do the math.

Comment: We should have a giant "no, bad dog" sign for any voltage divider power supply question.

Comment: Ok so the answer is 'it's a very bad idea'. That doesn't make it a terrible question as the downvotes would suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When unloaded the R divider will generate 3.3 V, but when you try to consume current (e.g. the ESP8266), the voltage will fall -- in this case to unusable levels.

To the ESP8266, this circuit looks like a 3.3 V source (which it wants), but in series with a resistance of 10k//20k = 6.66k ohm. Thus if it tries to consume current, the voltage will fall, and it won't function.

Nothing will melt.

You could probably use 2-3 diodes in series to drop the 5 V to 3.3 V (actually 5-2*0.7 = 3.4), but this isn't very stable (likely the 5 V is variable and may be as high as 5.5 V which would damage the ESP8266.