# Voltage divider design for 4 V, 2 A output

Tags: voltage-divider

I have a 12 V, 1.25 A supply and want to make it 4 V, 2 A using a voltage divider design. What method should I use for this design?

Comment: You should not use a voltage divider at all. Useful link: http://XYproblem.info

Comment: Use a buck regulator and not a voltage divider.

Comment: Even if a voltage divider *would* work, it definitely can't increase current. You can't increase the current of a DC supply by any linear method.

Comment: [Why voltage dividers don't work as power supplies.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/651639/115106)

Comment: A voltage divider will give you the voltage for a fixed current.  Bigger problem is you want 2A from a 1.25A supply.  Investigate buck convertors.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the term "voltage divider" is a vocabulary mismatch, what you need is a buck DC-DC converter to get 4V at good efficiency.

Here is a [list of candidates](https://www.mouser.fr/c/power/dc-dc-converters/non-isolated-dc-dc-converters/?number%20of%20outputs=1%20Output&output%20current-channel%201=2%20A%7E%7E5%20A&output%20voltage-channel%201=450%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E510%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E590%20mV%20to%205.1%20V%7E%7E591%20mV%20to%206%20V%7C%7E600%20mV%20to%205%20V%7C%7E600%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7E%7E600%20mV%20to%206%20V%7C%7E690%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E700%20mV%20to%205%20V%7E%7E700%20mV%20to%208.5%20V%7C%7E750%20mV%20to%204%20V%7E%7E750%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E752.5%20mV%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E800%20mV%20to%204%20V%7E%7E800%20mV%20to%206%20V%7C%7E900%20mV%20to%205%20V%7E%7E900%20mV%20to%206%20V%7C%7E1%20V%20to%205%20V%7E%7E1%20V%20to%207%20V%7C%7E1.2%20V%20to%205.5%20V%7E%7E1.2%20V%20to%206%20V%7C%7E1.75%20V%20to%205%20V%7C%7E1.9%20V%20to%205%20V%7C%7E2.5%20V%20to%2012.6%20V%7E%7E2.5%20V%20to%2015%20V%7C%7E3%20V%20to%2018%20V%7E%7E3%20V%20to%206%20V%7C%7E3.3%20V%20to%2015%20V%7E%7E3.3%20V%20to%205%20V%7C%7E4%20V&instock=y&sort=pricing&rp=power%2Fdc-dc-converters%2Fnon-isolated-dc-dc-converters%7C%7EOutput%20Voltage-Channel%201%7C%7EOutput%20Current-Channel%201) (I filtered on current and voltage).

Here's a [nice cheap one](https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/281/MYLSM00502ERPL-1219185.pdf).

I picked one with adjustable output because 4V is not a common output voltage, so it is not available in fixed output voltage version.

You can [design one](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator) if you want but if you only need one to solve a problem, readymade ones are faster to implement.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work.

Voltage dividers reduce predictably the voltage of signals, not the voltage of power supplies.

You need a switching DC-DC converter (step-down a.k.a. buck regulator) instead.

See [When would I use a voltage regulator vs voltage divider?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/when-would-i-use-a-voltage-regulator-vs-voltage-divider)

Comment: The difference is that a voltage divider reduces the voltage of a signal predictably. It reduces a power supply voltage unpredictably.

Comment: @GodJihyo the difference is that a "signal" wire is something that carries a quite small current whereas a "power supply" wire carries a relatively large and sometimes unpredictable current.

Comment: Specifically, voltage dividers work when the next stage's input is high impedance (relative to the divider impedances); most power supplies by necessity need to have very low-impedance outputs.