# Using +24VDC to get +12VDC and -12VDC

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, voltage-regulator, circuit-protection

I have the following circuit in my breadboard. My intention is to split a +24VDC into +12VDC and -12VDC. I'm using MC79M12 with [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/173525/ONSEMI/MC79M12BT.html) datasheet for the negative output and UA7821 with [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/843721/TI1/UA7812.html) datasheet for the positive voltage output. My goal is to power a circuit with op-amps from a +24VDC.

I was hoping to get +12VDC at node `a` and -12DVC at node `b` to power the op-amps relative to GND. But the voltage source goes from CV to CC automatically and the voltage regulator gets heated pretty quickly (to the point of feeling it by the smell). I don't measure -12VDC at node b; in fact, I measure a positive voltage, which is pretty small. I can imagine that the regulator is maybe reversed-biased and I'd need a -VCC for it to work... but theoretically it seems plausible to work since my GND is the 24/2 = +12V.

I've connected the input pin of both regulators to the +24VDC input voltage;
I've connected the ground pin of both regulators to the common ground of the circuit;
I've connected the output pin of the LM7812 regulator to the positive terminal of +12VDC output
I've connected the output pin of the LM7912 regulator to the negative terminal of -12VDC output.
Finally, connected loads and capacitors as suggested in the datasheet (I took into account the polarity of C4 and C5, which have + side to the GND).

But it is not working. What am I doing/thinking wrong here?
If it is not possible doing it this way, how could I split the +24VDC into +12VDC and -12VDC?

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: What is D2 for?

Comment: As said, that won't work. But why can't you power the op-amps from +24V? The op-amps will see 24V supply whether you power them with +24V and 0V, or +12V and -12V.

Comment: @Justme Because they need a +ve and a -ve to work, don’t they? Or should go just as a reference?

Comment: @ludicrous They don't specifically **need** a +ve and a -ve to work, it depends what kind of circuit you want to build out of an op-amp.

Comment: @Justme I think I see what you mean. So I could just power an op amp with 12VDC at +ve and 4VDC at -ve? The consequence would be that the “ground” would be 8V on my circuit?

Comment: @ludicrous I have no clue why you selected those voltages, but you could. But simpler to use just 24V and 0V, but you can select any voltages you want and they don't have to make sense. And you can still have 0V as ground.

Comment: @Justme but those 0V at the -VE of the op-amp is not the ground of the circuit, right? I think you are opening my understanding of op-amps. I didn’t imagine that would work

Comment: @ludicrous people have been making single supply op-amp circuits since 1960s, I bet whatever problem you may have understanding op-amps, it's solved already.

Comment: As others have said I think this is just a misunderstanding of what analog supplies mean or do. In a dual supply circuit with +/- 12V, Ground is said to be the center point between these supplies. Many opamp circuits need this "center" node in some form. You can convert any such circuit to single supply though; if your opamps are supplied with just +24v, then you need to create +12v as your center. This arrangement is usually called a virtual ground and often you will want to buffer it, eg with an extra opamp. All voltages in the circuit will be shifted identically.

Comment: @AaronLinnell on that case, the 0V will be my "new -12V", the +12V will be my "new GND" and the +24V from the source will be my "new +12V"? So if I place my oscilloscope's positive probe at 24V and ground probe at 12V will it present the signal as if it was +12V? Is there any risk on doing this? For example, if I have a component with max value of 16V, can I just link it to the +24V and +12V with no issue?

Comment: Yes, the component should be rated with a voltage between supplies. Keep in mind that most chips require all inputs to fall within the supply rails too, so you should not apply +25v or -1v relative to the new ground. As for connecting a scope, you just need to make sure you don't create a short-circuit path; most scopes probe grounds are also attached to the scopes power ground (ground pin of your AC plug) ground. If your device under test is battery powered or otherwise galvanically isolated (or if your scope is) this is no issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't work, I'm afraid. A look at the 79xx datasheet should show you that it regulates an already negative power supply - and you don't have one. It can't magically convert positive supply to negative.

You need a DC-DC converter or a negative voltage buck converter.

---

Your MC79M12BT is very unlikely to have survived.

Comment: what about if I do a voltage divider with two equal resistors and connect the middle node into ground? Would that work?

Comment: For reference? Yes... For using as power supply? No..just think, load will change resistance

Comment: [Why can't I use a voltage divider as a power supply?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/651639/115106)